# Error al imprimir datos desde api .NET

Tags: c#, .net

estoy ocupando una API de ligas de futbol con .NET, la transformo de json a un objeto y pasando  con `ViewBag` a la vista. Cuando lo quiero imprimir me llega como nulo.
Aqui esta la clase:

```
namespace consumir_api.Controllers
{
   class Countries
   {
      public string  countryId{ get; set; }

      public string countriyName { get; set; }

   }
}
```

el controlador:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

namespace consumir_api.Controllers
{
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
      public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
      {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        var json = await httpClient.GetStringAsync("https://apifootball.com/api/?action=get_countries&APIkey=0fa4f05e7f7e95c4d9efbb3cf2a405f85c53350a8dcf40ba1311dfcde751da4f");

        ViewBag.result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Countries>>(   json );

        return View();
       }
   }
}
```

vista:

```
<div class="jumbotron">

    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th> Id</th>
                <th> Nombre</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach ( var countries in ViewBag.result )
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @countries.country_id 
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @countries.country_name
                   </td>  
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>   
    </table>

</div>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo edites tu código para que el ApiKey sea un falso. También coloca en tu pregunta el Json resultante de llamar a la Api externa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Renombra tus propiedades de la aclase Countries a:

```
public class Countries
{
    public string country_id { get; set; }

    public string country_name { get; set; }
}
```

para que coincida con el JSON.

El problema es que el json esta viniendo en este formato:

```
{"country_id":"163","country_name":"Champions League"}
```

y no estaba coincidiendo con el nombre de tus propiedades:

```
public string  countryId{ get; set; }
public string countriyName { get; set; }
```